# WebServiceMock causing "CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending" when creating managed package

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, callout

I have a number of test methods that call `Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new SomeWebServiceMockImpl());` where `SomeWebServiceMockImpl` implements WebServiceMock.

These test methods pass when I run the tests via:

- Setup > App Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution.
- Setup > App Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > *class name* > Run Tests.
- Eclipse > Run Tests
- the Developer Console Tests tab

However, when I try and create a managed package that includes these tests they fail with the message:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out

I understand that this message usually appears after performing DML inserts/updates - see [Testing HttpCallout with HttpCalloutMock and UnitTest Created Data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/testing-httpcallout-with-httpcalloutmock-and-unittest-created-data). As such, I've been careful in these test methods not to make any database calls.

**Why are these tests failing during the managed package creation but otherwise passing?**

I remember reading about this recently but can't recall where. I suspect it is a known issue. I thought the work around was to execute the Mock tests first, so I moved them all to the top of the class and prefixed them with 'aaa_'. This didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the same thread as Daniel Ballinger's answer, [BBeaird points out](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Testing-Webservice-Callouts-with-Winter-13-Test-setMock-fails/m-p/573481#M105244) that wrapping the mock callouts in `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` also works around the bug.

Comment: I would say this is really the recommended path.  It actually kind of makes sense - using the mock interface simply puts it in the same context as waiting on a future call, scheduled task, etc.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely stuck this morning. My code was working without the start/stop test last week so I was baffled when it stopped working this morning. Your post here really made a difference! I implemented it and it was the solution!

Comment: I found that this didn't work for me until I created my test data using @testSetup. This presumably creates it in a different execution context so the mock callout isn't running after a DML operation in its own execution context.

Answer (score 12):

I found the post that mentioned this issue and the work around solution.

[Testing Webservice Callouts with Winter '13 Test.setMock fails because of Test Data creation.](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Testing-Webservice-Callouts-with-Winter-13-Test-setMock-fails/m-p/531257#messageview_3)

colemab:

> ... this appears to be a known issue in the deployment tool for Winter 13.
> Basically the deployment tool isn't running each class as an
> individual run during predeployment testing and so **this error will
> popup for new classes with call outs that run after test classes that
> do any DML.**   Which is just about every class right?
>
> Please note
> that since the deploy tests are different than the run all tests (for
> unknown reasons), you will never see this kind of error until you
> deploy to production.
>
> Since the tests on deployment run in alpha
> order, the workaround from support was to take my new class and name
> it very high alpha sort like 'aaa' so that it could run before any DML
> in other classes.
>
> Support didn't provide a ETA for a fix and didn't
> say if this would be listed on the official known issues list.

So I created a new class with "aaa_" at the start of the classname and added only the test cases using Test.setMock to it. I can now create the managed package with the tests otherwise unchanged.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty crazy, and would have been very hard to troubleshoot without internal SFDC knowledge.

Comment: @Mikey I think I was lucky that I had stumbled past that post recently and vaguely recalled it. Certainly an unexpected feature/gotcha in the HTTP callout functionality.