# Is a test method isolated from effects of other test methods

Tags: unit-test

Suppose I have test class `TestClassName` with two test methods:

```
@isTest
private class TestClassName {
    static testMethod void testMethodName() {
         // DML to insert data 
    }
    static testMethod void testMethodName() {
        // is inserted data available here?
    }
}
```

In other words, are all test methods isolated — as if a complete `tearDown` was performed after the execution of each test method?

Comment: There can be isolation issues between test classes. See [UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/unable-to-lock-row-error-while-running-all-apex-test-classes)
and [WebServiceMock causing “CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending” when creating managed package](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4326)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crap, I've misread the question! Yes, they're isolated!

---

There are no equivalents of jUnit's `setUp` and `tearDown` but each method is independent of other methods. If you need `setUp`, you have to write it yourself - create a small `private static void prepareTestData()` with all your DML and explicitly call it at the beginning of your test methods.

Actually it might be marked as public - will save you time if you can reference them from other test classes. It's still within a test class so it's unaccessible from regular code and does not count towards Apex storage usage.

There used to work a neat trick that would let you have some kind of "initialization block":

```
@isTest
private class TestClassName {
    private static Acount testAccount;

    static {
       testAccount = new Account(Name = 'science, baby');
       insert testAccount;
    }

    static testMethod void testMethodName() {
    }
    static testMethod void testMethodName() {
    }
}
```

This doesn't work anymore :( If you have only 1 test method it should work, but each subsequent one will not see the data crated in this static block.

Comment: Thanks! Although, my question is whether I can *rely* on there being no side effects. I don't mind preparing my data, as long as I'm safe from data from one test not influencing other tests.

Comment: I'm an idiot ;) Yes, you'll be completely safe, all variables will be reset, transactions rolled back etc. But if you use @seeAllData=true and need exclusive access to some resources you must bear in mind many tests can run at same time - read about SELECT...FOR UPDATE syntax.