# Uncommitted Work Error with MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock

Tags: callout

I am using the MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock to test a callout to Twitter. I am using the Test.Start/Stop to wrap the test.mock implementation which has previously fixed the issues we all had with using DML and Mock. Any ideas why the code below is causing the error again?

```
private static void testTwitterBatch () {

//Setup Custom Settings
social_media_settings__c sms = new social_media_settings__c(Name = 'Twitter');
sms.URL__c = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=';
sms.API_Key__c = 'KEYPUBLIC';
sms.API_Secret_Key__c = 'KEYPRIVATE';
insert sms;

Contact c = new Contact (
LastName = 'Test Twitter 1', 
Twitter_Username__c = 'britishboyindc');
insert c; 

Test.starttest();

MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multimock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
multimock.setStaticResource('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', 'TwitterBearerResponse');
multimock.setStaticResource('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=britishboyindc', 'TwitterResultsResponse');
multimock.setStatusCode(200);
multimock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');


        // Set the mock callout mode
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multimock);

        TwitterStatsUpdate_batch tb = new TwitterStatsUpdate_batch();
        tb.query = 'Select Id, Twitter_Username__c, Twitter_Followers__c from Contact';
        database.executebatch(tb,50);

Test.stoptest();
```

Comment: I narrowed down the issue a bit - the batch calls a class that does the actual callout to Twitter - if I invoke my twitter class directly from my test, everything works fine - but if use the method above and call it via a batch, I get the uncommitted error, even if I use seealldata=true and make no DML inserts...

Comment: If anyone ends up here, SF confirmed that Batches and Callouts in a test context like this don't work...they are hoping (safe harbor) to address that limitation in Winter 15...

Answer (score 1):

I've never found testing batches to be particularly friendly. I often fake the asynchronous process by just calling the relevant methods directly which helps avoids issues with `StartTest()` and `StopTest()` and data not being what you expect.

Maybe trying something like this will fix your issue?

```
TwitterStatsUpdate_batch tb = new TwitterStatsUpdate_batch();
tb.query = 'Select Id, Twitter_Username__c, Twitter_Followers__c from Contact';
tb.execute(null, tb.start(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

[WebServiceMock causing "CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending" when creating managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/webservicemock-causing-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-whe)

This is a very known issue .In summer 13 salesforce has come up with solution.You can go through summer 13 guide .For time being there are workarounds in the link above you can try those .

Comment: Actually, I don't think that is exactly the issue but rather this:
Asynchronous Apex operations result in pending uncommitted work that prevents callouts from being performed later in the same transaction. 
Sounds like that should also be fixed in Summer 13...

Answer (score 0):

Webservice and HTTP mock implementations do not currently work well when used in conjunction with classes implementing Batchable interfaces.

`The work around that has been suggested is to call the start, execute, and finish methods directly.`

When attempting to run batch classes in test methods using the mock implementations, you will get the uncommitted work pending even if you did not perform any DML. I surmise it has to do with the backend DML require to queue the batch but I have no proof of that....

Comment: see http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/06/18/batchable-class-test-data-callouts-how-to-test/ for code sample

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - Can you mark this as an acceptable answer as per your comment so it does not keep getting bumped by the community bot? (Or feel free to pick another answer)