# You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out error in test class

Tags: apex, integration

I have a requirement to create subscriber third party API. So here is a requirement before callout:

1. I need to do callout for getting the inventory name from thirdparty before creating subscriber.
2. Then I need to get the value of subscriber then pass it to create a subscriber.

I'm getting a error in test class  System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.

Please help me because it's a production issue.Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance

Thanks
Akshit Jain

Comment: Can you share the test class you have written? Thats a common error which salesforce gives if you are doing a DML and callout in same transaction. YOu can use `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` as per your requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46438/unit-test-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-please-commit-or-rollback-before-c)