# Testing Batch Job with HTTP Callouts

Tags: batch, callout, unit-test

Suppose I have the following:

```
global class CMBatchRegisterUsers implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

    global final String orgID = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    global final String query;

    global CMBatchRegisterUsers(){
        this.query = 'Select Id,Email from User where IsActive=true';
        System.debug('Organization ID: ' + this.orgID);
    }

    global HttpRequest buildRequest(String email){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.example.com?user_email=' + email);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(60000);
        return req;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<User> scope){
        HttpRequest req;
        Http http;
        for(User u: scope){
            http = new Http();
            req = this.buildRequest(u.Email);
            http.send(req);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}
}
```

So far I can test 50% of this code however when I try executing the batch as shown below, I always get `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`.

```
static testMethod void testBatchRegisterUsers(){
        CMBatchRegisterUsers c = new CMBatchRegisterUsers();
        System.assertEquals(c.orgID, UserInfo.getOrganizationId());

        HttpRequest r = c.buildRequest('test@test.com');
        System.assertEquals(r.getEndpoint(), 'https://www.example.com?user_email=test@test.com');
        System.assertEquals(r.getMethod(), 'GET');

        Test.StartTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CMMockHttpRegistrationResponseGenerator());
        Database.executeBatch(new CMBatchRegisterUsers());
        Test.StopTest();
}
```

The error seems to be thrown exactly where I do the `http.send(req);`.

Can someone point out the proper way to test a batch with callouts in it? My Mock callout doesn't seem to be helping. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here is the Mock generator as requested.

```
@isTest
global class CMMockHttpRegistrationResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('[{"success":true}]');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**PS.**
If I change the `executeBatch` to `Database.executeBatch(new CMBatchRegisterUsers(), 1);` it throws the error:

`System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.`

Comment: During testing try limiting the SOQL query to return only one user. Also, can you add the Apex for CMMockHttpRegistrationResponseGenerator to the question? It might be doing DML operations.

Comment: Sure thing, i have added the CMMockHttpRegistrationResponseGenerator. About to try limiting the query.

Comment: I've seen very similar issues before. See [Testing HttpCallout with HttpCalloutMock and UnitTest Created Data](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/testing-httpcallout-with-httpcalloutmock-and-unittest-created-data) and [Testing Webservice Callouts with Winter '13 Test.setMock fails because of Test Data creation.](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Testing-Webservice-Callouts-with-Winter-13-Test-setMock-fails/m-p/510495/highlight/false#M94938). Are you using SeeAllData=true or running any other test cases at the same time?

Comment: Also Ideas: [Allow loading test data prior to callout testing](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jcfAAAQ). If DML in other test cases is causing the issue, try adding a `aaa_` prefix to the class that contains testBatchRegisterUsers().

Comment: Yes I am running other test cases at the same time (not using SeeAllData). Do you think this may be causing it? I am relatively new to Apex but I don't understand why its saying `uncommitted changes`. I did not alter anything in the database.

Comment: Ok I moved my that `testBatchRegisterUsers()` into an entirely new test class and I am still getting the uncommitted changes error. If I comment out the `http.send(req);` the test passes so clearly its the callout that's causing the `uncommitted changes`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When testing HTTP callouts in Apex, I generally have a Helper Class, with static methods which returns the response I am expecting from the webservice, and in my code, where the `http.send();` would normally go, I use this instead.

```
HTTPResponse resp;
if(!Test.isRunningTest())
{
     resp = http.send(req);
}
else
{
     resp = MockApiCalls.WebserviceExpectedResponse();
}
```

I know this isn't particularly clean, but unfortunately this seems to be the only way to properly test http callouts for now. There seem to be improvement coming in the future, in the last release they included [Testing Web Service Callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) but you still get the problems you are facing

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

This is because in test deployments, all tests still run in one context, and you run into the Cannot do a DML statement before doing a webservice callout problem.

**Second Option**

*This only works when you only have 1 webservice callout to test in your entire test code.*

You can name your test class which does the webservice testing `AAATestClass`. Which causes your test to be executed before all the rest, and you don't run into the earlier mentioned problem. This is because tests are ordered by test class alphabetically and executed in that order.

Comment: Nice, i used this trick and it seems to be working! I hope they release that fix soon, thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by PJC, the Summer 13 release notes make reference to this exact issue on page 234 and appear to suggest that this problem goes away if you follow their example...but the example they give isn't 100% clear in my view!

Comment: So as an update - I have a sandbox on summer 13, and I still can't get this to work...looks like you can make a different async call as part of a test, and then a make a callout, but this doesn't seem to address the need to test an async call that makes a callout using a mockclass (like example above) - I am still getting uncommitted error...

Comment: Your uncommitted error means that you are trying to do a DML statement (insert, update, upsert, delete) BEFORE doing a webservice callout, in the SAME CONTEXT. Try to figure out where the DML comes from, and put it after the webservice callout.

Comment: Summer 13 does seem to fully fix the DML problem (It actually seemed to be working with API 27) so long as the MockCallOut request is contained within test.StartTest/StopTest methods. I have a test that does that and works fine. But if I create a batch within my test, try to set a mockcallout and then execute the batch that makes a callout, then I still get the uncommitted error, which is a shame...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Now on Summer '14 and still having same issue.  I can use MockCallOut within Test.startTest/stopTest and my REST webservice test completes using Mock class.  However, I have a batch job that calls the same webservice. If I set MockCallout and then execute batch I get the "uncommitted work pending" exception.  Looks as if we still can't test BatchApex with callout using MockCallouts.  Anyone have updates?