# Attempt to dereference a null object

Tags: exception, null

I am running tests on the following code:

```
global class CarrierTrackingBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts{

global String ShippingStatus;
global String query;
global String ShipmentStatus;
global Boolean constant;
global String savedShipping;
global String XmlReturn;
public static String trackingReturn;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   String Delivered = 'Delivered';
   String query = 'select Tracking__c,Shipping_Status__c from ShippingTest__c WHERE Shipping_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:18';
   String ShippingStatus = 'Shipping_Status__c';
   return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    for(sObject o : scope){
        constant = false;
        trackingReturn = (String)o.get('Tracking__c');
        if ((String)o.get('Shipping_Status__c') == 'Delivered'){
            constant = true;
            savedShipping = (String)o.get('Shipping_Status__c');
        } else {
            constant = false;
        }
        HttpResponse res;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + (String)o.get('Tracking__c'));
        req.setMethod('GET');
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            req.setEndpoint('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + (String)o.get('Tracking__c'));
            req.setMethod('GET');
            Http http = new Http();
            res = http.send(req);
            System.debug('Not a test');
        } else {
            System.assertEquals('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + (String)o.get('Tracking__c'), req.getEndpoint());
            System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
            String nullline = '\\n';
            String nulllinerepeated = nullline.repeat(39);
            String filler = '<';
            String fillerrepeated = filler.repeat(49);
            res.setBody(nulllinerepeated + fillerrepeated + 'Delivered<no>');
            System.debug('A test');
        }
        XmlStreamReader reader = res.getXmlStreamReader();
        String XmlReturn = res.getBody();
        XmlReturn = XmlReturn.replace('<',' <');
        XmlReturn = XmlReturn.replace('>','> ');
        String[] xmlcut = XmlReturn.split('\\n');
        System.debug(xmlcut[40]);
        String XmlProcessed = xmlcut[40];
        XmlProcessed = XmlProcessed.replace(' ', '');
        XmlProcessed = XmlProcessed.substring(53);
        String XmlDualProcessed = XmlProcessed.split('<')[0];
        System.debug(XmlProcessed);
        System.debug(XmlDualProcessed);
        String ShipmentStatus = '';
        ShipmentStatus = XmlDualProcessed;
        o.put('Shipping_Status__c', ShipmentStatus);
        if (constant == true){
        o.put('Shipping_Status__c', savedShipping);
        } else {
            o.put('Shipping_Status__c', ShipmentStatus);
        }
    }

    update scope;

}


global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
}
```

I am getting an error stating:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I am familiar with this error but I cannot see why I am getting it.  It is referenced towards **line 45**, which is

```
res.setBody(nulllinerepeated + fillerrepeated + 'Delivered<no>');
```

I am just confused.

Comment: It looks like the only other possibility is that your `res` variable is null. Can you edit your post to provide more of your code so that we can see where/how `res` is being declared & defined?

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: Damn it @DerekF solved it in the comments before I could hit submit on my answer again! Guy is a speed-demon ;)

Comment: I'm not normally so quick. Must've rolled out of bed with +5 agility today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HttpResponse object is still null, as you are not instantiating it.

After line 28 you need to do something like

```
res = new HttpResponse();
```

or indeed make line 28:

```
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
```

to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Are there still issues with tests for batch apex using a helper class that implements the `HttpCalloutMock` interface as per [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)?  The best information I could find is in the comments on [this accepted answer on another question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11607/24889). If mocking the callout is viable, OP would be able to remove the `else` block (and the assertions into the test class)

Comment: @DerekF You should be able to mock the callout properly. I had a helper class that was used to perform mock responses that could be controlled from the unit test itself. The accepted answer you linked to is two years old, and definitely dated.