# Test class List Exception: Controller cannot find test data

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, list

I'm testing a class as a community user. Here is the issue. my debugs show that running user is set. My User query returns a user with a contactid but for some strange reason the contact query is empty. The if statement is executed but no contact is returned. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

```
 public class myClass{
        public myClass(){
            Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            User user = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: runningUserId AND IsActive =:true][0];

        if(user != null && user.ContactId != null){
           Contact userContact = [select id from Contact where id=:user.ContactId][0];

        }

 }
}
```

Test Class

```
 @isTest
private class myClass_Test {

    static testMethod void myTestClass(){

        Id p = [select id from profile where name='Community Profile'].id;

        Account ac = new Account(name =' Community Account') ;
        insert ac; 

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName ='testCon',AccountId = ac.Id);
        insert con;  

        User user = new User(alias = 'test123', email='test123@test.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p, country='United States',IsActive =true,
                ContactId = con.Id,
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='tester@test.com');

        insert user;



        system.runAs(user) {
            Test.startTest();
               myClass controller = new myClass();

            Test.stopTest();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what is the OWD model for Contact? What operation is the Community User trying to do upon its related Contact via the VF controller?

Comment: It's like the community user can't access their own Contact record.

Comment: Have a read of this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18901/102). It has some details on creating Communities Portal Users, Roles, and Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me the issue is with the code that you're trying to test:

```
if(user != null && user.ContactId != null){
           Contact userContact = [select id from Contact where id=:user.ContactId][0];
```

In the above, you're querying for a single Contact record and you've not specified a list, yet you've used `[0]` at the end of your query as though it was returning a list. That should be removed from your query unless you change the definition to `list<Contact>userContact` in which case you could leave the `[0]` at the end of your query.

I recommend you simply remove the `[0]` instead. If for some reason it won't compile, you can always use `limit 1` in your query.  That will solve any issues you might have with the compiler so it can resolve the query to a single contact.