# Method defined as testMethod do not support web service callouts, test skipped

Tags: unit-test, webservices, httpcalloutmock, webservicemock

I have been struggling with this error for a few days now. I get this error every time I try to run a test for a method that has an httpCallout. I followed the architecture from  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm, but to no avail. I thought it could be something I was messing up in my code, so I copied all three of the classes from the documentation, and I am still getting the error when I try to run the test. All of the classes are on Salesforce API 29. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to include test.isrunningtest in your actual callout class to check you are not going to run actual callout and only test mock. take a look on this thread

[Testing HttpCallout with HttpCalloutMock and UnitTest Created Data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/testing-httpcallout-with-httpcalloutmock-and-unittest-created-data)

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5070/7709 this answer did it! Thanks so much! You are a god among men! I was banging my head against the desk with this error for a while now.

Comment: Although this fixes the problem, you shouldn't do this in must cases. You'll want to actually test your code with a mock response and should follow alex answer.

Comment: ok, I will follow @Jose. Thanks for your quick response...lol

Answer (score 38):

You need to call `Test.setMock(...)` in your test class once you've implemented the required interfaces to prevent this particular error message.

You shouldn't need to use `Test.isRunningTest()` to test your call outs (and doing so give you untestable code).

Comment: If I used Test.setMock(), wouldn't I have to put that in every single test class that might end up making a callout due to triggers and flows?  Wouldn't one concise Test.isRunningTest() check that prevents the actual callout or creates a mock at that point be more reasonable?  It seems unreasonable to have to go back and rewrite 20 test classes because I added a trigger.

Comment: @Codezilla, another option would be to use a `@testSetup` method which would setup the Test.setMock

Comment: @TimLewis That will not work. Only the state of the database is retained from `@testSetup`. `Test.setMock()`, `Test.setCurrentPage()` etc do not work in the way you'd like.

Comment: Can we use a Test.isRunningTest to call Test.setMock ?

Answer (score 6):

Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts Stack Trace: null

This error occurs because web service callouts are not allowed in Test class.

To bypass callouts add HttpcalloutMock class.

Here is a sample test class with the mock class to bypass web services Callout.

**********************  Test Class ***************************

```
@isTest 
private class Test_class {

    private class RestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            String fullJson = 'your Json Response';

            HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');
            res.setBody(fullJson);
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
    static testMethod void service_call() {

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new RestMock());
        Test.startTest();

        //your web service call code

        Test.StopTest();


    }
}
```

The mock class will take care of webservice callouts.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't create  DML statements** before calling your test API callouts.
You should put all your DMLs in a separate function with a @TestSetup

```
@TestSetup
static void makeData(){
    Lead lead = new lead(
        FirstName = 'Test First Name',
        LastName = 'Sample Last Name',
        Phone = '555-555-5555',
        MobilePhone='+15555555555',
        Company = 'Some Test Company'
    );
    insert lead;
    lead1 = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Lead LIMIT 1];
}

@istest
static void Controller_CodeCoverage_Test() {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new RequestCalloutMockClass());
    Test.startTest();
    // your web service call code
    Test.stopTest();
}
```